# How to configure the GPIO pins on an STM32L152?

Tags: assembly, stm32, cortex-m, stm32ldiscovery, stm32l152

I got an STM32L discovery board that contains an stm32l152rb microprocessor. I try to program that board in assembly without any library at all. So far I succeeded in writing linker scripts and a basic routine that copies the .data section into the RAM and zeroes out the bss section. But apart from that I am a little bit lost.

As a tiny experiment to understand how configuring GPIo works, I want to make a program for the board that lights the green LED connected to GPIO port B, pin 7. Reading the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf), I conclude that I need to do the following two things:

1. Configure GPIO port B, pin 7 as an output pin
2. Set said pin to high

But at this place, I figuratively don't see the forest for the trees. I am not sure which of the multiple IO modes avaible I should choose and all these acronyms confuse me. I would really appreciate somebody giving me detailed information, instruction and possibly example assembly on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using GPIO module you must do the following:

1. Reset the GPIO registers:

   - RCC module, register `AHBRSTR`, bit `GPIOBRST` set to 1 - rst high
   - RCC module, register `AHBRSTR`, bit `GPIOBRST` set to 0 - rst low
2. Enable GPIO registers clock:

   - RCC module, register `AHBENR`, bit `GPIOBEN` set to 1 - Enable clock

After that you can start using GPIO registers

1. GPIO module, register `GPIOB_MODER`, bitfield [15:14] set to 01 -
   General purpose output mode
2. GPIO module, register `GPIOB_OTYPER`, bit 7 set to 0 - Output push-pull
3. GPIO module, register `GPIOB_OSPEEDR`, bitfield [15:14] set to 00 - 400 kHz Very low speed
4. GPIO module, register `GPIOB_PUPDR`, bitfield [15:14] set to 00 - No pull-up, pull-down

Now you can use either `GPIOB_BSRR` (set/reset) register or GPIOB_ODR (output) register:

- GPIO module, register `GPIOB_BSRR`, bit  7 set to 1 - Set GPIOB pin 7
  (high)
- GPIO module, register `GPIOB_BSRR`, bit 23 set to 1 - ReSet
  GPIOB pin 7 (low)

Comment: Wow. That is nice. Thank you!

Comment: And much more difficult than I did originally think.

Comment: Why is the GPIO reset needed?

Comment: I do it only to bring GPIO registers into default state, when I touch GPIO hw for the first time. It is not required to do it in other cases.